# Can I disable EF Core error logging on transient errors that will be retried?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

When I use `EnableRetryOnFailure` in EF Core, I'm getting error-level logs on every transient error. The vast majority of the time these transient errors are safe to ignore, since the transaction is about to be retried and will probably succeed.

However, I don't see any way to differentiate in the logs between the situation a) "retrying because of a transient error" and b) "all allowable retries have failed." Ideally, the former would be a lower-severity LogLevel, or would be wrapped in some kind of `SqlTransientRetryException`, or something else.

This is an issue for me as I don't want to be getting alerts calling my attention to every transient exception, but I also don't want to just screen out any `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query` error log, because if the error isn't transient or all allowable retries have failed, then I want to know about it.

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at the [Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging) section of the EF Core documents, the documentation for the [DbLoggerCategory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbloggercategory?view=efcore-2.1) class, and poked around the code on GitHub, and it does not seem like there is any distinction made for transient errors... as far as logging goes.

I think the best thing you can do would be to raise an issue to the team about it. Perhaps they can introduce a category for transient failures.

As a stretch (and I haven't checked) maybe there is something distinct about the logging messages themselves. If there is you could conceivably write a logging sink that filters these by looking at the content of the message. That seems to be hackish and not a good use of time.

Another possibility would be to suppress all the logging and wrap your calls; when a "real" non-transient exception finally bubbles out, you can log that.

Comment: How would I suppress all the logging and log only non transient exceptions?